# Will cooking tagliatelle in squid ink turn it black?

Tags: pasta, color, squid

I am planning to make squid ink pasta, but I do not have pasta machine. Since I am lazy, I want to boil dried pasta in squid ink water. Will it turn black...or not black enough?

Comment: You can make hand rolled squid ink pasta.  Then you wouldn't need a pasta machine and you could have black pasta.

Comment: Ok i am just lazy lol

Comment: In that case, you can certainly purchase squid ink pasta.

Comment: Not readily available here

Comment: Funny you editted my question lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boiling it in ink will give some flavor and color, but it won't be part of the pasta.  Instead, you could make a squid ink-based sauce to toss it in afterwards.  Here's an example recipe: https://www.thespruceeats.com/spaghetti-al-nero-di-seppia-2018653

Comment: I planned to mix it in hollandaise-carbonara situation which was a bad idea. Yours is better solution